# How subscriber keys are being added in Marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, subscriber, subscriber-key

I am not getting this quite easily

If I have a DE, and I have multiple fields in it, and one is mapped as subcribey key ( ID let's say ), and id value is : 00848-454-555585545ds for one of the row, and there is an email field as well

Does that mean if I go to All subscribers and search by this id in the search by subscriber key tab, I am supposed to find the subscriber with the right email address ? right ?

bUT When I do that I find nothing

Example :

My DE properties and subscriber key

[image]

Two records :

[image]

If I look for this subscriber after a while, nothing is found :

[image]

Any detailed explanation on how this works exactly

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: did an email get sent to this subscriber? we only add to all subs when a send is attempted

Comment: No, it wasn't attempted, Thanks for this, I have to send an email to check this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subscriber Key values are set in the following ways:

1. An import into All Subscribers
2. An API call that sends a message (in all channels)
3. A send to a Data Extension that has a sendable field mapped
4. An integration that includes a Subscriber Key mapping

I may have missed some of them, but in most cases a send has to occur for it to show in All Subscribers -- at least for email.

Comment: +1 on this. Plus the fastest route for testing is to simply add via the UI.